# Proving that a matrix and its transpose are similar

Tags: matrices

This is a well-known fact, several proofs have been outlined on Math.Se but they all rely on arguments involving Jordan normal form or modules,  which are beyond my reach.

Does anybody know of a more elementary proof?

Comment: Do you know about Smith Normal Form?

Comment: This is out of reach as well (it's related to modules right?)

Comment: I don't know of any proof of this that doesn't use some sort of canonical form. Jordan normal form is probably the most accessible and is definitely worth learning about.